# SPO Site SWAP Communications site with Tree View/ left panel structured navigation

Tags: sharepoint-online, powershell, navigation, team-sites, communication-site

I'm trying to invoke a site swap using powershell.

```
Invoke-SPOSiteSwap -SourceUrl [site URL] -TargetUrl [site URL] -ArchiveUrl [site URL]/sites/archive
```

I get the error message: The Site is not a communications site or it has the classic publishing feature enabled.

First thing to admit is yes I'm trying to site swap a modern Communications site For a modern Teams site.
The reason is because I need to be able to activate site navigation elements.

In an effort to preserve the original user experience I'm attempting to use the Left panel Structured navigation.

As far as I am able to find, a modern Com Site only has the top navigation available hence needing to swap for a team site. Now we circle back to me trying to invoke a site swap for a teams site so I can use the left panel navigation.

Is there a way to enable structured left panel navigation on a modern com site? Is there a way to invoke a site swap that allows for switching between a modern Com site to a modern teams site?

Any help or direction would be very appreciated.

Comment: Is the source site or target site hub site? If yes, unregister it as a hub site, swap them. BTW there is no way to add left structural navigation to communication site.

Comment: Thank you for your response. Currently there are no sites registered as a hub site. I'm attempting to do a site swap from a communications site to a teams site. I get the error message: Invoke-SPOSiteSwap : Errors: [0]; Warnings: [1]; Details: The Site is not a communications site or it has the classic publishing feature enabled.

Both the Communications and Teams site have publishing turned off.